# Can two people from two different locations fly on the same plane?

Tags: airlines, stopovers, miami, oslo, icelandair

My girlfriend and I live apart, I'm in Toronto and she lives in Oslo. On Oct 20 I'm planning to fly to Oslo via Reykjavik, while my return flight to Toronto will be on Oct 26 via the same stopover in Iceland.

How can my girlfriend book the same flight from Oslo to Toronto that I'll be on if she also flies with Icelandair?

BQ: We'll be flying to Miami right after we land in Toronto which would seem strange. I'm wondering if you could fly from Oslo straight to Miami instead. But then I wouldn't be flying a round-trip, Toronto-Oslo-Toronto per se since I didn't depart from Miami originally.

Comment: I'm totally not getting the question here...

Comment: If you flew Toronto-Oslo-Miami-Toronto, it's related to an open-jaw ticket. Completely possible in general.

Comment: I *think* what's going on is that the BF wants to fly Toronto–Oslo–(Toronto)–Miami, and his GF wants to fly Oslo–(Toronto)–Miami, and they want to be on the same Oslo–Miami itinerary.

Comment: Confused here. Same flight on the same day in the same direction means the same plane. Why are you wondering if its possible for two people to be on the same flight? Surely you are not going to be alone on the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your plans correctly (they are not particularly clearly formulated): You're flying Toronto->Reykjavik->Oslo, meeting up with your girlfriend. Then you both want to fly to Miami, via Toronto (and Reykjavik)?

You'll have to check with Icelandair, but it will probably cost more to buy Toronto-Oslo-Miami than Toronto-Oslo-Toronto, but it should be possible, and probably cheaper than Toronto-Oslo-Toronto-Miami.

Icelandair probably only has one plane leaving Oslo for Miami/Toronto and any time, so if you both book the same flight you'll end up on the same plane. There are other questions here on how to go about getting to sit together.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to have two people flying on two different itineraries that happen to share the same flight, you have to buy two separate tickets that both include these flights.

However, once you have done this, it is usually possible to call the airline and "link" the two itineraries so that they are aware that you are traveling together.  I'm not sure how much of an effect this has, apart from perhaps getting seat assignments together (depending on how the airline does this, and the fare class of the tickets you bought) and avoiding situations where one person gets bumped from an overbooked flight while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange question. And not very well-formulated. What doesn't compute is the basis of the question. You book your tickets, your girlfriend books hers, you'll be in the same planes. What would make you think that an Orwellian entity would prevent you from doing that?

If you meant sit together, that makes more sense. You might have to talk to the airline, to arrange sitting together. If the airline offers online check-in and selection of the seats, one of you could grab a seat first, inform the other, who can then select (hopefully) the seat next to it.